# Why is the result different in the same environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```py
import numpy as np

my_rects = np.array([[ 518,  792,  646, 1080]])
relative_rects = np.array([[ 16,  53, 116, 286.]])
crops_width = my_rects[:, 2] - my_rects[:, 0]
crops_height = my_rects[:, 3] - my_rects[:, 1]


def expand_rects(rects, img_width, img_height, width_ratio, height_ratio, epsilon=1e-5):
    W = rects[:, 2] - rects[:, 0]
    H = rects[:, 3] - rects[:, 1]
    center_x = (rects[:, 0] + rects[:, 2]) / 2
    center_y = (rects[:, 1] + rects[:, 3]) / 2

    res = np.zeros_like(rects, dtype='float32')
    res[:, 0] = center_x - W * width_ratio / 2 
    res[:, 2] = center_x + W * width_ratio / 2
    res[:, 1] = center_y - H * height_ratio / 2
    res[:, 3] = center_y + H * height_ratio / 2

    res[:, 0] = np.clip(res[:, 0], 0, img_width)
    res[:, 2] = np.clip(res[:, 2], 0, img_width)
    res[:, 1] = np.clip(res[:, 1], 0, img_height)
    res[:, 3] = np.clip(res[:, 3], 0, img_height)

    return res

print(expand_rects(relative_rects, crops_width, crops_height, 1.2, 1.1 ))
```

After running this, I got the result of:

```
5.999996  41.34999  126.       288.
```

However, the first element should be 6.0 instead of 5.999996(66−1.2×(116−16)÷2 = 6). 
What's more, if I put the function into another big file, with the same input, the output becomes:

```
6. 41.35 126. 288.
```

My environment is:

```sh
Linux (none) 4.9.37 #1 SMP Tue Nov 13 10:04:52 CST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@(none):/jkklklk/projects/# python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Is there an explantation for this? I really need the result to be stable(it should be 5.9999996 every time).

Comment: What are you running this on? You see to be having problems with floating point precision, but the error is surprisingly large for a computation this simple and small, so I'm wondering if you're running it on old or small hardware? And when you say "running this", do you mean from the CLI or saved as a .py and run like that ?

Comment: Yes, I run it on a Hisilicon SoC as a saved .py file.

Comment: Any chance that the version that's producing more accurate results is using `float64` instead of `float32` for the results array?

Comment: Actually, I want the result to be 5.999996 rather than 6. So maybe I should set dtype to ```float16```?

Answer (score 1):

Representing float values is a very old issue with some computer languages (Python included). You can read a bit more here, in the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

This specific part from it might give you a hint:

*Many users are not aware of the approximation because of the way values are displayed. Python only prints a decimal approximation to the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored by the machine. On most machines, if Python were to print the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored for 0.1, it would have to display:*

```
>>> 0.1
>>>
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Lastly, if you want to have a consistent output, you'll have to cast it to an integer or use the [`round()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).